# Column editing using awk or sed. how to print the following pattern?

Tags: sed, awk, solaris

`Sample Input:`

```
title          role        subject
name-JOHN      student      math
school         state        NY
county         street       Phone
name-TOM       student      math
school         state        TX
county         street       Phone
name-LILLY     student      math
school         state        LA
county         street       Phone
name-ROSY      student      math
school         state        WA
county         street       Phone
garbage line 1
garbage line 2
```

`Desired Output`

```
JOHN     NY
TOM      TX
LILLY    LA
ROSY     WA
```

bottom 2 Garbage lines must go away. i want to use AWk or SED?

I am running Sun OS.

Comment: Your edit completely changes the data and makes all of the answers useless: don't do that.

Comment: Yes, your edit completely changes the question. You went from three fields to two and completely different text. Please [accept](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one of the answers below by clicking on the check mark to their left. Then, post your new, different question separately (make sure to give us both your OS and the real problem you're trying to solve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another awk way (which,  I now see, is just an uglier version of @Costas's):

```
$ awk -F'[- ]' '($1~/name/){k=$2}($1~/school/){print k,$NF}' file
JOHN NY
TOM TX
LILLY LA
ROSY WA
```

---

You can also use `grep`:

```
$ grep -oP '^(name-\K\S+|school.*\s+\K.*)' file | paste - -
JOHN    NY
TOM TX
LILLY   LA
ROSY    WA
```

In your particular example, of course, you could just look for CAPITAL letters:

```
$ grep -Eo '[A-Z]{2,}' file | paste - -
```

---

Or perl:

```
$ perl -lne '$n=$1 if /^name-(\S+)/; /^school.*\s+(.+)/ && print "$n\t$1"' file
```

Or another perl:

```
$ perl -007ne 'print join "\n", (/name-(\S+?)\s.*?state\s+(..)\n/gsm)' file | paste - -
```

Comment: i have changed my question description. usage of grep in my OS is limited to following options Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file

Answer (score 5):

By GNU `sed`

```
sed -n '/^name-/{s///;N;s/[a-z].*\s//p}' file
JOHN      NY
TOM       TX
LILLY     LA
ROSY      WA
```

By GNU `awk`

```
awk -F'[ -]+' '/name/{a=$2}/state/{print a,$3}' OFS='\t' file
JOHN    NY
TOM     TX
LILLY   LA
ROSY    WA
```

By `grep`

```
grep -o '[[:upper:]]\{2,\}' file | paste - -
JOHN    NY
TOM     TX
LILLY   LA
ROSY    WA
```

Comment: i am getting an error. sed: command garbled: /^name-/{s///;N;s/[a-z].*\s//p}             i am using solaris 10 with korn shell

Comment: @ayrton_senna Try to substitute `\s` by `  `(<space>)

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/name/ {gsub(/name-/,""); printf "%s\t",$1} /school/ {print $3}' file
JOHN    NY
TOM     TX
LILLY   LA
ROSY    WA
```

Comment: awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line   my awk man page doesnt have gsub or printf options.   is there any other way to do this

Comment: @ayrton_senna when asking here, you always need to tell us your operating system. Your errors suggest that you're not using a GNU system. Please edit your question and tell us what OS you're on.

Comment: @jasonwryan i change my question description. Can you help now?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, are you using the "old `awk`" (`/usr/bin/awk/`) or the "new `awk`" (`/usr/xpg6/bin/awk`)? An online [man page reference](http://www.manpages.info/sunos/awk.1.html) and [GNU Awk's help page](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Names.html#Names) specifies the distinction quite clearly.

Assuming if you are referring to "new `awk`" where you can use variable assignments via `-v`, you can also consider this:

```
$ awk -v RS='name-' -v OFS='\t' 'NR>1{print $1,$6}' sample.txt
JOHN    NY
TOM     TX
LILLY   LA
ROSY    WA
```

We set the record separator (`-v RS='name-'`) so that `awk` interprets the name and state as the first (`$1`) and sixth (`$6`) fields respectively. We then also set the *output* field separator (`-v OFS='\t'`) to perform the desired formatting. The `NR>1` condition is just to skip the first line.

**edit**

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="name-";OFS="\t"}NR>1{print $1,$6}' sample.txt
```

This should be doable even for "old `awk`" too, please do test it out. Keeping the "new `awk`" initial suggestion still.